# scrollTo JS plugin not working on iPad - flickering

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://chronox.comxa.com/

that's my site, if you click any link on the nav ON AN IPAD it will flicker and try to scroll down, but then just go to top of the page.

Works perfectly on desktop.

Why no ipad? Anyone got any idea?

Comment: I know some clicks of events are not triggered by touch. It's maybe you're problem

Answer (score 0):

Is the flicker happening when you try to scroll back up?

If so that's due to the setTimeout function or setInterval function having not completed its time duration yet.

Comment: No it happens whenever I click the nav buttons. Even if I've just opened the page and want to scroll down, it flickers. It looks like it tries to go to the #thing but also trying to go to # (the top of page) which is causing the confused flicker.